# Bayesian Hierarchical Clustering

Tags: hierarchical-bayesian

Do you know if we can implement Bayesian Hierarchical clustering (python or R) on vectors with float values? I have searched through the web, and just found some random matrices with the values of 0,1,2. In the related paper nothing has mentioned. I also tried to implement it with R, which returned a fatal error and R studio and RGui were closed suddenly, which I am not sure if it is because of the float values or not.

Answer (score 0):

**BHC** Package in R is specially designed for bayesian hierarchical clustering